# Enable/disable text input when a different radio input is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two input radio and one input. I want to disable the text input if click radio button value is `exam-two` and enable it if `exam-one` value is selected. How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="tekcift-yon"]').click(function(){
        $('.attr-sys').attr('disable').siblings().attr('disable');       
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="exam" value="exam-one" /> Exam one</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="exam" value="exam-two" /> Exam two</label>

<input type="text" class="attr-sys" value="exam to click disable this input" />
```

Comment: Can you make it a bit clear what you are trying to achieve? its not clear whether you are disabling the text input or the radio button, also there is no input with this selector `input[name="tekcift-yon"]`

Comment: When the radio button with the value "exam -two" is pressed, disabled to name to input class="attr-sys".
And if click again radio button with the value "exam-one" is pressed, enable to name to input class="attr-sys"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when "exam-two" radio input is clicked, you want the `disabled` attribute of the "attr-sys" input set?

Okay.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.attr-sys');
function clickExamTwo() {
  input.disabled = true;
}

function clickExamOne() {
  input.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="exam" value="exam-one"
  onclick="clickExamOne();"/> Exam one</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="exam" value="exam-two"
  onclick="clickExamTwo();"/> Exam two</label>

<input type="text" class="attr-sys" value="exam to click disable this input" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by attaching event listener to change event on radio buttons, check for the value and based on condition add disabled [prop](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) to input, here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="exam"]').on('change', function(){
       if($(this).val() === 'exam-two') {
         $('.attr-sys').prop('disabled', true);  
       }
       else {
         $('.attr-sys').prop('disabled', false);  
       }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="radio" name="exam" value="exam-one" /> Exam one</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="exam" value="exam-two" /> Exam two</label>

<input type="text" class="attr-sys" value="exam to click disable this input" />
```